# jQuery Image Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to do an image array for a gallery, The gallery has around 10-20 images I'm just unsure on how to actually make an image array in jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
 arrayOfHTMLImageElements =    $('#gallery_container img').get();
 orJqueryCollectionOfImages = $('#gallery_container img');
 arraySourcesOfImages =   $('#gallery_container img').map( function(){ return this.src })
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the images in `<div class="some_img">`, and then:

```
var m = []
$('.some_img').each(function() { m.push ($(this));});
```

Don't actually use that code; format it first, but, that's the general idea.

Comment: jQuery objects store matched elements in an Array. `$('.some_img').get()` will return an Array of all the matched HTMLElements.